# SEO Friendly Urls using htaccess

Tags: seo

My site [www.sellGuru.in](http://www.sellGuru.in/) has lots of 404 errors reported by Google webmaster but these urls are accessible from browsers. I can't figure out why these errors have been reported by the webmaster.

My site htaccess file redirect everything to index.php?page=pagename but Google webmaster is not able to find pages like sellguru.in/contact redirected to => sellguru.in/index.php?page=contact using htaccess file.

Below is the HTaccess FIle i am using

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

pls help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be explicit in your RewriteRule. As written, it isn't passing anything to the "page" argument of the script.  It should look something like this:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]`

`^(.*)$`  will capture the content after RewriteBase, "contact" in your example, and store it in $1.

`index.php?page=$1` tells Apache how to handle the URL, in this case it will treat is as a call to index.php?page=contact